# UITapGestureRecognizer crashing app when clicking on collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to allow user interaction in my collection view. I have decided to try to implement UITapGestureRecognizer to do this. I have tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the collectionview itself and to the collectionview cell. Both ways crash the app. Here is how I am adding the UITapGestureRecognizer to the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell



          cell.userImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath))

           cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].username
           cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID


        let singleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "segueToProfile:")
               singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
               singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

        return cell
    }
```

When I tap on the cell I get a SIGABRT in the AppDelegate. The error message reads "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". What am I doing wrong. UITapGestureRecognizer.

This is my segueToProfile function:

```
    func segueToProfile(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
//        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended){
//            print("myUIImageView has been tapped by the user.")
//        }
        print("hell world")

    }
```

Comment: There might also be a stack trace and a more detailed failure message, and any of those might be helpful. Could you check?

Comment: how do I get more detailed failure messages? I am new to Xcode and can only see what is in the debugger console atm. As in stack trace do you want what appears when you type "bt" into the console?

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why you are using gesture recognizer rather than the default cell selection method?

Comment: You should have used didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method of collection view delegate instead of custom tapGesture.

Comment: @udbhateja didSelectItemAt() does not work. My collectionview does not respond to user input. I have checked all the user interaction fields and they are all set to true but it still does not work. do you know how to make it so didSelectItemAt() works?

Comment: @DevKyle didSelectItemAt() does not register my user input. I have checked all available resources and nothing is helping me make it so that user interaction works. Do you know of another way to make user interaction possible on a collection view cell?

Comment: @NickSteen yep, what appears under `bt` and possibly some text near the "terminating with uncaught exception..." message in the console. For more info I'd suggest checking the good old [Xcode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW1).
But I agree with others here, you shouldn't need to manage your own `UIGestureRecognizer` to just handle item selection in a collection view.

Comment: @NickSteen - I added an answer for you to address why didSelectItem isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `didSelectItemAt` method of collectionView your codebase look readable and maintainable.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
currentViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueName", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: didSelectItemAt does not work. My collection view does not respond to user interaction. do you know why this can happen?

Comment: Maybe you've still tapGestureRecognizer somewhere and it prevents selection of cell. Check them, that should be the problem.

Comment: Just in case, does the collection view have the `delegate` assigned?

Comment: @GlebA. The collection view delegate is being assigned with collectionview.delegate = self. is there another way to do this?

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci I was trying to do didSelectItemAt() before I the gesture recognizer. didSelectItemAt() does not work at all. do you have any other ideas as to why?

Comment: @NickSteen provided the `didSelectItemAt` is implemented in the same class, that should do the trick. You can always `print` the delegate later on to make sure it's assigned.

Comment: @GlebA. what do you mean by printing the delegate?

Comment: I mean adding lines like `print(collectionView.delegate)` somewhere in the code where you expect the delegate to be already assigned, just to validate your assumptions. Debugging by logging, basically :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get rid of `tapgesturerecognizer` as `didSelectItem` should handle what you are trying to accomplish. That being said, in order for this to work you must:

1. Remove `tapgesturerecognizer`
2. Ensure that the collection view delegate is set to self.

e.g. `<yourColletionViewName>.delegate = self`

Above can be assigned at `viewDidLoad()`